# Does Mongock support Mongo version 2.x?

Tags: mongock

I have to execute migrations on the mongo server version: `2.6.10`. I use `mongock-springboot` `5.2.4`, spring boot version `2.7.2` and `spring-data-mongodb` version `3.4.2`.

I don't think it's possible[1], but I'm not sure hence the question.

[1]

- I see that both `mongodb-springdata-v2/v3-driver` use `mongodb-driver-sync` that does not support legacy wire protocol.
- In the maven repo, I see old drivers under `com.github.cloudyrock.mongock`, but neither use `mongo-java-driver` that would allow me to use old wire protocol. (except `mongodb-v3-driver` - but it is for `v3` [f.e. read/write concerns are used])

---

**Is it possible to use mongock with mongo db 2.x ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you are right. As MongoDB being in version 6.x, Mongock doesn't provide support for earlier versions than 3.x.

You can see MongoDB compatibility table [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/compatibility/)